# Unable to resolve module ../Utilities/Platform - Expo Web

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web, expo-web

I'm trying to run my expo react native app in web, but i'm getting this error:

Unable to resolve module ../Utilities/Platform from C:app\frontend\frontend\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\PaperUIManager.js:

None of these files exist:

- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\Platform(.web.ts|.ts|.web.tsx|.tsx|.web.js|.js|.web.jsx|.jsx|.web.json|.json|.web.cjs|.cjs|.web.scss|.scss|.web.sass|.sass|.web.css|.css|.web.cjs|.cjs)
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\Platform\index(.web.ts|.ts|.web.tsx|.tsx|.web.js|.js|.web.jsx|.jsx|.web.json|.json|.web.cjs|.cjs|.web.scss|.scss|.web.sass|.sass|.web.css|.css|.web.cjs|.cjs)
  15 | const NativeModules = require('../BatchedBridge/NativeModules');
  16 | const defineLazyObjectProperty = require('../Utilities/defineLazyObjectProperty');

> 17 | const Platform = require('../Utilities/Platform');
> |                           ^
> 18 | const UIManagerProperties = require('./UIManagerProperties');
> 19 |
> 20 | const viewManagerConfigs: {[string]: any | null} = {};

Call Stack
MetroBundlerDevServer.getStaticResourcesAsync (node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.js)
process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues)
async MetroBundlerDevServer.getStaticPageAsync (node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.js)
async (node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.js)

i have already defined a webpack.config.js and added config.resolve.alias['../Utilities/Platform'] =
'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform';

tried to check find the package in the modules and solve the problem but wasnt a sucess, tried to create the webpack config using expo customize:web but nothing changed

Comment: Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: Any update? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Same issue here, it seems that there is only ../Utilities/Platform.ios.js in the given location

Comment: Could you please include package.json?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.
I checked out my git repository step by step and found an import that was causing the issue for me.

```
import NativeSafeAreaView from "react-native-safe-area-context/src/specs/NativeSafeAreaView";
```

After I removed this import and stopped using it in my code, the error message disappeared. Hope it will helps